# Passing two different lists of data for each instance of a child component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, flux

I am new to ReactJS and I am using the react-search npm package:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-search

I have a page that is rendered to order foods. There are two react-search components, one corresponds to foods you would like to receive today and the other for 'later'. Thus I am passing through the same list of foods to both instances of reactSearch:

```
<label> Add for now: </label>
<ReactSearch list={foods} updateFoods={this.updateNowOrders}></ReactSearch>
<label> Add for later: </label>
<ReactSearch list={foods} updateFoods={this.updateLaterOrders}></ReactSearch>
```

The ReactSearch code is as follows:

```
import Search from 'react-search'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'

export default class ReactSearch extends Component {

    update(foods) {
        this.props.updateNowOrders(foods);
        this.props.updateLaterOrders(foods);      
    }

    render () {

        var foods = this.props.list;

        return (
        <div>

            <Search foods={foods}
                    placeholder='Search foods'
                    maxSelected={}
                    multiple={true}
                    onItemsChanged={this.update.bind(this)} />
        </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Here I am attempting to pass the new list of foods (selected foods) for each component back to the create order component.

Now the first issue here is that I will get a *TyperError: this.props.updateNowOrders* is not a function, when I attempt select some orders for later. I appreciate this is bad design. I have tried to separate thee two via try & catch blocks, with e instanceof TypeError... but this does not work.

The second TypeError I am getting is within the order component. When the food list is passed back with those that need to be ordered... I then get *TypeError: Cannot set property 'selectedForNow' of undefined.* 
The implementations of the two functions are as follows in the order component:

```
constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);

    this.state = {
        foods: [],
        selectedForNow: [],
        selectedForLater: []
    };

};

updateSelectedForNow(data) {         
    this.setState.selectedForNow = data;
}

updateSelectedForLater(data) {     
    this.setState.selectedForLater = data;    
}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TyperError: this.props.updateNowOrders**

This happens because your property isn't called `updateNowOrders` but `updateFoods`, You should probably use the same name, `updateOrders` for example:

```
<label> Add for now: </label>
<ReactSearch list={foods} updateOrders={this.updateNowOrders}></ReactSearch>
<label> Add for later: </label>
<ReactSearch list={foods} updateOrders={this.updateLaterOrders}></ReactSearch>
```

**TypeError: Cannot set property 'selectedForNow' of undefined**

You can read [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate) about setState. It's a method that you should use like this:

```
updateSelectedForNow(data) {         
      this.setState({selectedForNow: data});
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Silly of me to forget ot this format :D I am however getting another **TypeError: this.setState is not a function**. 

When trying this.state.setState({selectedForNow: data}); 
I get **TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined**. 

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Ah I needed to add **this.updateSelectedForNow = this.updateSelectedForNow.bind(this)**  etc. in the constructor. All working well now. Thanks for your help!